# AlpineJs select box bind text not the value

Tags: laravel

I want to bind the text of select option to the text of a span.
I want to display the text of select box, not the value.

```
<div class="w-full flex" x-data="{category:0}">
        <div class="relative w-auto" >
                 <span x-text="category"></span>
        </div>
        <select id="category" class="cursor-pointer" x-ref="category" x-model="category">
             <option value=0 selected="selected">One</option>
             <option value=1>Two</option>
             <option value=2>Three</option>
       </select>
</div>
```

Now, when I select option, the span displays - 0, 1, 2.

I want to display "one", "two", "three" instead which are the text of select option.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you need is to add a reference for your `select` after that
you can access the `options` collection

and you can access your selected one by get it's index from `selectedIndex` property

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.8.1/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
<div x-data="{category: 0}">
  <h1 x-text="$refs.categoryEL.options[$refs.categoryEL.selectedIndex].text"></h1>
  <select x-model="category" x-ref="categoryEL">
    <option value="0">one</option>
    <option value="1">two</option>
    <option value="2">three</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Joseph, Thank you for your answer. I know it should work.
But the point that I have 50+ options in the select box.
So it is hard to list them in a array.
I think there might be another solution?
```<option value="61" data-textvalue="sixty-one">``` and  we can extract this data-textvalue?

Comment: check the answer again i found a solution for it

Comment: @GlobalKnowledge there is another update check out the `selectedIndex`

Comment: Thank you so much @Joseph 
Can I still get the value of option?
In fact, I am also using Livewire with this Alpine. I need to submit the value to livewire backend side

Comment: Yeah of course the value saved in `category` variable